# Is there a way to specify the timeout of a HTML5 video element?

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm looking for a way to set the timeout before a HTML5 video element reports a network error ([HTML5 media element error code 2](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/media-elements.html#dom-mediaerror-media_err_network))

While testing, I've noticed that if I stop the internet connection, the video element hangs and is seemingly buffering for a very long time before displaying a media error code 2. Can I reduce this time at all?

There have also been some instances where it doesn't report the error at all and it seems to buffer forever. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you cannot, it depends of each browser vendor implementation. According the HTML5 Video [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/video.html) within **resource fetch algorithm** you can read:

> The **stall timeout is a user-agent defined length of time, which should be about three seconds**. **When a media element that is actively attempting to obtain media data has failed to receive any data for a duration equal to the stall timeout, the user agent must queue a task to fire a simple event named stalled at the element**.
>
> User agents may allow users to selectively block or slow media data downloads. When a media element's download has been blocked altogether, the user agent must act as if it was stalled (as opposed to acting as if the connection was closed). The rate of the download may also be throttled automatically by the user agent, e.g. to balance the download with other connections sharing the same bandwidth.
>
> User agents may decide to not download more content at any time, e.g. after buffering five minutes of a one hour media resource, while waiting for the user to decide whether to play the resource or not, or while waiting for user input in an interactive resource. **When a media element's download has been suspended, the user agent must set the networkState to NETWORK_IDLE and queue a task to fire a simple event named suspend at the element. If and when downloading of the resource resumes, the user agent must set the networkState to NETWORK_LOADING**.

Comment: Is there a way to fake or simulate an Media Error Code 2 to test that is handled correctly/elegantly?

Comment: `MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK=2. A network error of some description caused the user agent to stop fetching the media resource, after the resource was established to be usable.` So, I guess, just unplug your internet and use the HTML5 events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events yo handle any possible error.

Comment: If the browser does not response, it might be a issue within the browser. The spec only describe the behaviour, the browser vendor is responsable about the implementation.